# Validator extend implicit not firing in AppServiceProvider

Tags: php, laravel, validation, recaptcha

I am trying to verify my recaptcha response on my form by posting to the url google provide, however I when I try to fire it via the AppServiceProvider it is not hitting it at all and skipping it. I can see the validator is working the FormRequest but for some reason it is not firing the Check function on my CaptchaValidator

Here is my AppServiceProvider

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        \Schema::defaultStringLength(191);

        if ($this->app->environment() == 'production') {
            \URL::forceScheme('https');
        }

        \Validator::extendImplicit('recaptcha', 'App\Validation\CaptchaValidator@Check',
            'You have not passed the recaptcha.');
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        if ($this->app->environment() !== 'production') {
            $this->app->register(\Barryvdh\LaravelIdeHelper\IdeHelperServiceProvider::class);
        }
    }
}
```

CaptchaValidator

```
<?php

namespace App\Validation;

use GuzzleHttp\Client;

class CaptchaValidator
{
    public function Check($attribute, $value, $parameters)
    {
        $parameters = http_build_query([
            'secret' => env('RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY'),
            'remoteip' => app('request')->getClientIp(),
            'response' => $value,
        ]);

        $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?' . $parameters;

        $client = new Client();
        $response = $client->request('post', $url);

        try {
            $results = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());

            return $results->success;
        } catch (\Exception $exception) {
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Request for the form with the validation

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class RedeemRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required|recaptcha',
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: You have in you service provider `App\Validation\CaptchaValidators@Check` but your class is named `CaptchaValidator` without *s*.

Comment: Sorry that was on purpose to see If I could get an error to throw, the problem still persists even If I rename it

Comment: Have you tried moving your code from the `Check()` method into a closure instead of using the class in your service provider? Also your method should `return false;` at the end after the try catch.

Comment: I have indeed no luck, its like it's completely ignoring this. I've even tried just changing it to other validation rules and it still doesn't trigger

Comment: Can you var dump inside your `rules()` method from your request class to see if it even gets triggered. If not please check your controller or edit your question with the code of how you use this form request class.

Comment: Yes it is being triggered, it is returning the array array:1 [▼
  "g-recaptcha-response" => "required|recaptcha"
]